# auto deduction of part of template types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to write simple template function which returns `n` lsb bits of given number, where `n` is template parameter, and I would like it to work with `uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t`. So I though of:

```
template<size_t n, typename T>
inline T align_to(const T& num) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "integer required");
    static_assert(n < sizeof(T) * 8, "overflow");
    return num & (Ones(n));
}
```

The problem is that typical usage would be:

```
align_to<4, uint64_t>(some_uint64_t_var)
```

where I would like the type `uint64_t` to be deduced automatically by the compiler and I of course want to provide `n`. so I'm looking for a way in which compiler deduces only part os template arguemtns.

Comment: Why not make `n` a function argument instead of template param?

Comment: Have you tried to just use the template as is and call it like `align_to<4>(some_uint64_t_var)` ?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, are you sure `static_assert(n > sizeof(T) * 8, "overflow");` is evaluating the correct expression?

Comment: fixed the second static assert

Answer (score 2):

Your `align_to` function will automatically deduce `T`. It can be deduced by passing `num` as an argument: [example on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vm02sL0fOw0L32DU).

```
template <std::size_t n, typename T>
inline T align_to(const T& num)
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    std::int32_t x = 100;
    align_to<16>(x); // `T` deduced as `std::int32_t`
}
```

See [cppreference - template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call) for an overview of the rules.